# Connect to Debian VPS box via VPN Issue

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn, vpn

I am kinda stuck with an usual issue (or is it usual?). Let me explain.

I have two Debian VPS boxes. The first one is a pure VPN (OpenVpn) and the second one is my regular server with emails, websites and all. I also have a machine "at home" that can easily connect to these two boxes.

Now I need to connect like this:
my machine at home to -> my VPS that runs VPN only and then to -> my regular VPS server.

I thought it would be easy, but I was mistaken. I allowed my VPN's static IP address through my firewall (iptables) on my regular VPS server but I didn't work. I flushed all the iptables just to see if it helps but.. it still doesn't work (it always times out, I use ssh keys to connect). I can only connect to either my VPS that runs my VPN only or to my regular VPS, but my route of home->VPN->regular VPS just doesn't work. How can I possibly do it? These two VPS boxes are working fine: My VPS with VPN is working perfectly well and my regular VPS is also working perfectly well. I would be really grateful for any pointers / suggestions / advices at all. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question. Not sure why it works this way but it works. I simply allowed "password logins" and it all started working perfectly well. It connects using ssh keys anyway without any password prompts but.. nonetheless allowing password logins in ssh solved the issue (I had it turned off earlier). Hope it will help someone too.